# I'm making a discord.py bot and want to search without an URL

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx,url):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()

    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'] [0] ['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
    sourcevar = url
    sourcevar = str(sourcevar)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Now playing.", url="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=889553173583368252&permissions=8&scope=bot", description="Now playing" ' '+ sourcevar, color=0xEC4444)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I get the message: **'song' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:song" ) to search YouTube**

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: what did you try to resolve it ? Did you try to do suggestions `--default-search "ytsearch"` or `"ytsearch:song"`? Did you check documentation how to use it?

Comment: maybe you should put it in `try/except` and when it raise error then run again with prefix `"ytsearch:"` - `extract_info( "ytsearch:" + url , ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try/except` to catch error and do as error messages suggests: add `'ytsearch:'` before value in `url`

```
extract_info( 'ytsearch:' + url , ...)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import youtube_dl

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}

url = 'song'

try:

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        # ... code ...

except Exception as ex:
    #print('Exception:', ex)

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info( 'ytsearch:' + url, download=False)
        # ... code ...
```